# glReadPixels performance not improving with PBO

Tags: opengl, c, picking

I'm currently using glReadPixels to read from the depth buffer to calculate where on the map the player is pointing, for the purpose of placing objects on the ground. I do this after rendering the heightmap, but before rendering all other objects, so I don't get a skewed result.

```
float depth;
glReadPixels( mouseX, windowHeight - mouseY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &depth );
```

This works fine, but as expected causes my frame time to go up from 15ms to 25ms.

I then tried wrapping the glReadPixels call within a PBO and using the value a frame or two later when it becomes available.

```
// Within data struct
GLuint pbo;
GLsync readSync;
float depth;

// Within init
glGenBuffers( 1, &pbo );

// ...

// Within render loop
if ( readSync != 0 ) {
    GLenum syncStatus = glClientWaitSync( readSync, 0, 0 );
    if ( syncStatus == GL_ALREADY_SIGNALED || syncStatus == GL_CONDITION_SATISFIED ) {
        glGetBufferSubData( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, 4, &depth );
        readSync = 0;
    }
}
if ( readSync == 0 ) {
    glBindBuffer( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo );
    glBufferData( GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 4, 0, GL_STREAM_READ );
    glReadPixels( mouseX, windowHeight - mouseY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0 );
    readSync = glFenceSync( GL_SYNC_GPU_COMMANDS_COMPLETE, 0 );
}
```

While this does work, I'm not seeing any performance improvement compared to the non-PBO method. I've read that some drivers can be fussy about reading from the depth buffer, but I get equal results when reading from the front buffer as well.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check the format of your depth buffer - if the parameters you pass to glReadPixels don't match, then your driver will need to do a format conversion.

Comment: After more testing, it looks like MSAA was the culprit. After disabling MSAA, the PBO method was noticably faster (impact was sub-1ms), compared to the original method. This adds more incentive for me to read from a framebuffer if I want MSAA on the front.